# I Have To Restart A Firestore SnapshotListener And I Don't Think That's Right

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

***UPDATED:*** I have a project that is using Firebase Firestore. I have snapshot listeners set up to my model objects. I start the snapshot listeners when the app starts. My understanding is that if you start a snapshot listener once that's all you need.

My issue is that when I create a new object in the app I must restart the snapshot listener in order for it to see the changes. I am wondering if I am making a mistake somewhere. Here are the files I think are important. If anything else is needed please let me know.

**Main**
Main where I create the environment objects for the project and start the UserRepository snapshot listener.

```
@main
struct TheExchangeApp: App {
    
    // @EnvironmentObjects
    @StateObject private var userRepository = UserRepository()
        @StateObject private var authListener = AuthSession(userRepository: UserRepository())

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(userRepository)
                .environmentObject(authListener)
        }
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.swift**
This is the user repository were I create the snapshot listener.

```
    class UserRepository: ObservableObject {
    
        // Access to Firestore Database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        private var snapshotListener: ListenerRegistraion?
        
        @Published var users = [User]()
        
        init() {
            startSnapshotListener()
        }
        
        func startSnapshotListener() {
            // Add a SnapshotListener to the User Collection.
        if snapshotListner == nil {
            db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                } else {
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("No Users.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    self.users = documents.compactMap { user in
                        do {
                            return try user.data(as: User.self)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

func stopSnapshotListener() {
        if snapshotListener != nil {
            snapshotListener?.remove()
            snapshotListener = nil
        }
    }
    
    func createNewUser(userUid: String, user: User) {
        do {
            let _ = try self.db.collection(FirestoreCollection.users).document(userUid).setData(from: user)

       if snapshotListener == nil {
            print("createNewUser snapshotListener is nil")
        } else if snapshotListener != nil {
            print("createNewUser snapshotListener is not nil")
        }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("UserRepository - createNewUser Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthSession**
Here I start a combine publisher on the userRepository snapshot listener. The publisher is not getting an update when I create a new user in SignUpView below. If I restart the snapshot listener in UserRepository I get the published value.

```
class AuthSession: ObservableObject {    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    var userRepository: UserRepository
    
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(userRepository: UserRepository) {
        self.userRepository = userRepository
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    func startCombine() {
        userRepository
            .$users
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { users in
                users
                    .first(where: { $0.id == self.currentUserUid})
            }
            .assign(to: \.currentUser, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**SignUp View**
Here is where I create a new user. The snapshot listener does not work unless I restart. I know because the combine publisher in AuthSession does not fire.

```
        struct SignUpView: View {
                @EnvironmentObject var authSession: AuthSession
                
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                
                var body: some View {
                    
                        Button(action: {
                            self.signUp()
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Sign Up")
                        })
                }
                
   func signUp() {
        authSession.listen()
        let newUser = User(email: myemail@email.com, name: "Hans")
        self.authSession.userRepository.createNewUser(userUid: user.uid, user: newUser)
        
    }
 }
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you disconnect the listener, it should continue to be active. If you add a `print` statement directly inside `db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener {`, does it show up for the change? If it does, the problem is in your downstream code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did add a print statement. It does not show up for the change. What odd is it only seems to be for this listener. I've tested it on other models and they work. I even start the listener in the signUp method.

Comment: Thanks for testing that. You might want to update the code in your question to include that print statement, and include its output too. Aside from that, I don't see where in the code you shared the problem would come from though, so I hope somebody else spots it.

Comment: I added a number of print statements today and have realized that when a new User is added to firebase or one is deleted the users array in UserRepository is not updated. I've verified this by printing after the User is added. I can see the User in the database but it does not show up unless the snapshot listener is recalled. I cna verify that it's been called once since printing the users array returns a number of users that were in the database when the app started. Somehow it seems the snapshot listener is being stopped but I don't call that anywhere.

Comment: It seems as if the snapshot listener stop when a user is created with email and password. When someone logs in the snapshotlistener works as expected. Is there anything from a setting perspective on database rules that would stop listeners on account creation?

Comment: Try holding on to the listener registration in your repository. See `MappingColorsViewModel`  in this article: https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#error-handling. Also, I'd move the code for adding a user into the user repo.

Comment: @PeterFriese I have updated the code to follow what I believe you meant in your comment. I've tried signing up a new user with the changes and the issues persists. I may have misunderstood what you meant. the changes are made in UserRepository and SignUpView.

Comment: @PeterFriese for sanity I added an if statement to the createNewUser method in UserRepository. When the new User is created I check to see if the the listener is nil. What's odd is it's not. This further confuses me. I can see the User in the database, but it's not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've sorted out the issue. A developer I am working with changed the rules on Firestore. These new rules included the following for the User collection.

```
match /users/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
```

Once I removed these rules everything works as expected. I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: Security rules are what keeps your and your user's data safe - you shouldn't remove them! Please check out the documentation to learn how to write the correct Security Rules for your data model.

Comment: I’ll add these back. I removed them for development only. Thanks @PeterFriese.